# Why the sizes are different in Chrome and Safari (Media Query Problem)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, media-queries

https://keuper-school.herokuapp.com/

I have used media queries but in safari browsers with smaller screen sizes, the sizes are different and cannot see some sections.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1256px) {
    .hots{
        flex-wrap:wrap;
    }
}
```

Its not wrapping properly. Sizes are wrong and some contents are missing

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: As jdfink mentioned, remove `display: flex` from body, or `height: 200vh` (if you need the display)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `display:flex` from the `body` of the page.